# Spliting date cell value that was submitted via Google Forms into a Google Sheet

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, split

I'm very new to JavaScript and and Google Apps Script. I'm having trouble using the `split()` function on the value of a google sheets cell that contains a date timestamp that was inserted by a google forms submission.

**Value in cell A3 is** `9/21/2018 13:26:05`, but it returns `Fri Sep 21 13:26:05 GMT-07:00 2018` in the Apps Script logger

**Value in cell J3 is** `Industry Tour *approval required` and it returns `Industry Tour *approval required` in the Apps Script logger

The following returns `Industry Tour` as expected.

```
var event = row[9].split('*')[0]; //splits value of J3 and returns part[0]
```

The following results in an error.

> TypeError: Cannot find function split in object Fri Sep 21 2018 13:26:05 GMT-0700 (PDT). (line 29, file "Code")

```
var submittedDate = row[0].split('GMT')[0]; //attempting to split value of A3
```

I'm looking for a way to split the value of A3 so that it only displays `Fri Sep 21 13:26:05`, but not the `GMT-07:00 2018`. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: It is a `Date`. You can simply format the column to display in a certain manner. Review JavaScript `Date` class if you are looking for script solutions to work with the timestamp value. The utc offset is valuable information in general and I do not advise erasing it

Comment: Tehhowch, thanks for your reply. I am not trying to replace it in the cell, but I am trying to send the result of the split data in an email. Any advice on splitting the `date object` is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Based on suggestions from elsewhere, I decided to convert the date object to a string using `String()` and then `split()` at the "GMT".

**Code below solved my problem**

```
var submittedDate = String(row[0]);
submittedDate = submittedDate.split('GMT')[0];
```

Comment: Why not [`Utilities.formatDate`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#formatDate(Date,String,String))?